# Conditional tag search-no-results

Tags: search, conditional-tags

Is there a way to make a conditional tag that tests if it is `search-no-results` page?

I know that there is a function to check if [`is_search()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_search) page:

```
if(is_search()){
    echo "search page";
}
```

But I didn't found a way to check for search-no-results, and I noticed that WordPress gives body class with `search-no-results` to this page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no conditional tag for no results on a search page, but you can create yourself one.

You basically just have to check the value of `$wp_query->found_posts`, if it is `0`, returns `false`, any other value, returns `true`

```
function is_search_has_results() {
    return 0 != $GLOBALS['wp_query']->found_posts;
}
```

Comment: Vote Up requires 15 reputation... :(  vote my question and maybe then i will can vote your answer

Answer (score 2):

Actually it should be like this.

```
function is_search_has_results() {
  if ( is_search()) {
    global $wp_query;
    $result = ( 0 != $wp_query->found_posts ) ? true : false;
    return $result;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use code like this in your search.php template :

```
if ( have_posts() ) {

    return default search results query

} else {

    Your custom query

}
```